# PDF App Engine Conversion

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

this is my second try to get an help.
I'm only trying to convert a PDF attachment in PNG, without success.

This is my code:

```
class FAX(db.Expando):
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        for elemento in mail_message.attachments:
            asset = conversion.Asset("application/pdf", str(elemento[1]), "Fax.pdf")
            conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "image/png")
            result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
            for elemento2 in result.assets:
                fax = FAX()
                fax.immagine = elemento2.data
                fax.put()

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This is the log:

```
0.1.0.20 - - [05/Apr/2012:02:04:33 -0700] "POST /_ah/mail/fax@faxmeraviglie.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 124 - - "faxmeraviglie.appspot.com" ms=558 cpu_ms=163 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.010690 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c45eeb741ec2540095a8ba3862842
```

Comment: Your log message indicates success. What problem are you actually having? You need to describe what part isn't working as expected.

Comment: I'm still fighting with this. In the logging.error(mail.message.attachments) there is: [('Fax.pdf', <EncodedPayload payload=#2644950956263091718 encoding=base64>)]. So there is something. I get no error in the Logs, so I suppose that the file is in the conversion. But I still have nothing stored in the datastore. I can't understand.